# Instance Level Public IP (ILPIP) static Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm create VM in AZURE and create reserverd ip.
After create relation between VM and reserverd ip.

How to make static Instance Level Public IP (ILPIP)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8UNY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right in the Portal (Preview Portal). Just click on your VM, Settings and goto Ipadresses.

There is an option to activate the Instance Level Public Ip.